# How to get variable, function symbols in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, clang, symbols, ctags

I want to get bootstrapped to analysis Visual Studio 2013 source.
To do that, I want to get a list of symbols of member variable, member function, local variable, class name, and so on.
I tried ctags, Clang.
ctags let me know some information, and easy to use it. But it doesn't show me local variables information.
Clang let me know about local variables, but compiling Visual Studio project with Clang is very difficult. :(
I heard Microsoft Visual Studio Language Service could help me, but it's not clear how to use it.

Is there any way to do get symbols, analysis codes? Can you provide the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze your Visual Studio 2013 source code with our [SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/) tool, which creates CSV files containing all the information you asked for: list of member variables, member functions, etc. You simply have to provide your project file in command line.